# SQL tables relationship and indexes

Tags: sql, sql-server, relationship

I want to have 2 tables SalesOrderHeader and SalesOrderLine with one to many relationship and also want to build indexes.

SalesOrderHeader table:

```
 SalesOrderNumber 
------------------
|                |
| 1              |
|                |
|----------------|
|                |
|                |
| 2              |
|                |
|                |
------------------
```

SalesOrderLine table:

```
 SalesOrderNumber Line
-------------------------
|                | 1    |
| 1              |------|
|                | 2    |
|----------------|------|
|                | 1    |
|                |------|
| 2              | 2    |
|                |------|
|                | 3    |
-------------------------
```

Please advise how  possible to build relatinships and indexes with these tables structure approach?

Comment: create a foreign key constraint ...

Comment: Index syntax is usually RDBMS specific, so you'd need to post what RDBMS you're using for this. Also, your table "design" looks a bit off. I think it should be 1 - 1 / 1 - 2 / 2 - 1 / 2 - 2 / 2 - 3.

Comment: Dear Rahul, MS SQL

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a foreign key

```
ALTER TABLE SalesOrderNumberLine
ADD FOREIGN KEY (SalesOrderNumberID) REFERENCES SalesOrderNumber (ID)
```

Afterwards create a nonclustered index on that column

```
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX IX_SalesOrderNumberLine_SalesOrderNumberID
ON dbo.SalesOrderNumberLine(SalesOrderNumberID);
```

Comment: Thank you, that's what I'm need!